# Relativelayout - how to use nested RelaitveLayout-blocks

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am trying to switch my app-layout from a LinearLayout to RelativeLayout. For me its important to keep a good code-structure andI I consider it more readable if I have a parent RelativeLayyout for the whole screen and then have nested Relative Layouts thats holding the Views.

for instance, I have a RelativeLayout that holds a **Spinner**, then under that I have a block that shows textviews and imageViews associated with **date**, and under that I have another Relativelayout that holds views asscociated with **time**.

This is how I organized the layout when using a LinearLayout. I want the same organization with Relativelayout. see below

```
|-----------------------------| 
| (SPINNER)  textview         |
|-----------------------------|
| (DATE) textView imageview   |
|-----------------------------|
| (TIME) textview imageview   | 
|-----------------------------|
```

that is - the child is organized in a sub-RelativeLayout (nested). And I thought I could just put the individual RealtiveLayouts beneath each other by just use an anchor-id
and then use

```
android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayoutDate"
```

that is the third block - time should be put under the the date-block

But obviously I am doing something wrong because all views is in the uppermost corner right now in the screen.

Here I post some part of the xml-layout file. Would be glad i someone knew whats wrong and how to fix it.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- spinner -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutSpinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/planets_spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spinnerrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinnerrow"/> 

</RelativeLayout>    


 <!-- date -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutDate"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayoutSpinner">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLabel_setDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="set date: "
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/dateImg"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textLabel_setDate"
        android:src="@drawable/date"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/setDate_txtView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dateImg"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/uncheckedImg"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/setDate_txtView"
        android:src="@drawable/unchecked"/>


</RelativeLayout>


 <!-- time -->
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayoutDate"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLabel_setTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="set time: " /> 

     <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/timeImg"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textLabel_setTime"
        android:src="@drawable/time"/>

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/setTime_txtView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/timeImg"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the code your using `match_parent` for all the RelativeLayout's, don't use `match_parent` for all sub-layout's. It will hide the previous one's.

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

make it only for parent and remaining should be `wrap_content`

Answer (score 0):

You should not create 3 relative layouts but just ONE and then use below & rightof on all views to display them properly, since this looks like a form however i would strongly suggest using GridLayout which is meant exactly for that, see documentation here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong and yet it appears to me that one closing tag missing.
You did open/created 4 Relative Layouts and yet I only could find 3 that closed.

```
1) <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    <!-- spinner -->
    2)<RelativeLayout
    2)</RelativeLayout>    
       <!-- date -->
       3)<RelativeLayout
       3)</RelativeLayout>
           <!-- time -->
           4)<RelativeLayout
           4)</RelativeLayout>
```